# React Native - context + firebase

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I need to pass one value from firestore to application context. I don't know where am I going wrong? Has anyone had a similar problem? I searched the website but couldn't find anything similar.

```
export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
const [user, setUser] = useState();
const [contextWeight, setContextWeight] = useState();
}

return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        setUser,
        contextWeight, 
        setContextWeight,

        unit: async () => {
            
            await firestore()
            .collection('users')
            .doc(auth().currentUser.uid)
            .collection('products')
            .doc('product')
            .get()
            .then(( documentSnapshot ) => {
              if( documentSnapshot.exists ) {
               
                setContextWeight(documentSnapshot.data().weightUnit);
        
              }
            }).catch(error => {
              console.log(error);
            })

     }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
```

Comment: You can't await in realtime there, so unless `unit` is to be called as a function in a child like `await unit()` then this code is not valid. You can't expect `unit` to be populated with the results of your `await firestore()` here.

Comment: How to approach it? Can you nudge more?

Comment: make `unit` into `getUnit` and then call it from your child like `await getUnit()` - but keep in mind you can't `await` within `render`/the body of the functional component - you'll need to use `useEffect` or something similar.